# Updating deep child objects on an Aggregate Root

Tags: domain-driven-design

How should I perform updates on nested children of an Aggregate Root?

Should I find the child object by traversal of associations and perform the update on it directly, or should I add a method on the Aggregate Root that takes care of it?

#### An example

I'm modelling an old project at our company which is a system we use to perform searches of customers against a suspicious person list:

### The model

- We run a `Batch Search` every night
- The `Batch Search` contains a list of `Searches` for it.
- Each `Search` contains a list of `Matches` and is associated with one `Customer`

### The process

- We check each `Match` and mark it as *confirmed* if it was a confirmed match.
- We also tick a checkbox for each `Search` if all it's `Matches` where *inspected*

[image: DDD model in diagrammatic form of the above description]

### The caveat

A `Search` can also run standalone, as in - not being a part of a `Batch Search`. In that case the `Search` naturally becomes the Aggregate Root.

### Question

> How should I be performing the update operations on the child items? The blue book states that all updates to children must go through the Aggregate Root.

There are 2 ways to perform this update:

#### Option 1

Traverse the graph and find the child object and perform the operation directly on it.

```
batchSearch = batchSearchRepo.find(1);
search = batchSearch.findSearch(5);
match = search.getMatch(3);
match.markConfirmed();
batchSearchRepo.save(batchSearch);
```

#### Option 2

Add a method on the Aggregate Root

```
batchSearch = batchSearchRepo.find(1);
search = batchSearch.markSearchMatchAsConfirmed(5, 3);
batchSearchRepo.save(batchSearch);
```

Which of the 2 update methods is more appropriate and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aggregate roots exist to protect the data within them. If you tear the aggregate roots internal structures and do operations on the internals directly without incorporating the aggregate root, the aggregate root can no longer validate the operation is valid.

In DDD the second option is not only more appropriate, it is the only correct way to go (as stated in the quote you posted).

---

When you however encounter the nesting that you have, you could also ask yourself a question whether your design is 100% correct.

1. Aren't perhaps some of the internals of `BatchSearch` aggregate roots on their own?
2. Couldn't maybe `Search` exist outside of the boundary of `BatchSearch`?
3. Does affecting a `Search` affect a `BatchSearch`?

If you answered *yes* to questions 1 and 2 and *no* to the third question, you have already eliminated one entire level on nesting and can now access a `Search` directly as a separate aggregate root. With this in mind, could you maybe to the same for a `Match`?

Comment: "Aggregate Roots exist to protect the data within them". Assuming that a `Search` is part of a `Batch Search`, every time a `Search` is marked as *inspected* I decrement a `searches_pending_review_count` counter on the `Batch Search`. Doesn't that make the `Batch Search` an Aggregate Root automatically? - As noted in the 'Caveat' section of my question though, a `Search` can exist standalone as well, in which case it becomes the Aggregate Root

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides If `BatchSearch` does provide the context for `Search`es to be made then having the `BatchSearch` is most likely necessary but operations have to flow through it. However, maybe even better idea would be to completely ditch the `BatchSearch` in favor of some process manager which would be working with events `SearchPreparedForInspection` and `SearchInspectionCompleted`. Creating a fold of the events would give you the searches which are yet to be inspected. I cannot tell you much more information without knowing a lot more about your domain.

Comment: That's OK, you've already answered a lot of my questions this far. Thanks.